# Angular Material Datepicker - select monday by default when other days of the week is chosen

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am new to Angularjs. I wonder is there any filtering mechanism for the Angular Material Date Picker(md-datepicker), So that I can choose only Monday when other days of the week is choosen, provided all the days are enabled. For example, when i clicked on 14-04-2016(Thursday), (11-04-2016)monday of that week should be automatically selected.

Let me know if any other details needed. Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a filter for your datepicker:

```
 <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-date-filter="onlyMondays"></md-datepicker>

 $scope.onlyMondays = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 1;
 }
```

Or if you want to let all days selectable you could change the date to monday in the background with:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="selectedDate"></md-datepicker>
```

you could set the date to the last monday afterwards:

```
var daysToSubstract = $scope.selectedDate.getDay() - 1; 
$scope.myDate.setDate($scope.selectedDate.getDate() - daysToSubstract);
```

Comment: Thank you @kabaehr for your contribution to my issue. I have added the above code as per my requirement. `$scope.onlyMondayToSelectStartDate = function (date) {
         var daysToSubstract = 6;
         if ($scope.filtersDat.selectedStartdate.Datecontent[0].getDay() != 0)
         daysToSubstract = $scope.filtersDat.selectedStartdate.Datecontent[0].getDay() -1;
         $scope.filtersDat.selectedStartdate.Datecontent[0].setDate($scope.filtersDat.selectedStartdate.Datecontent[0].getDate() -daysToSubstract);
         return false;
 }`

Comment: How could you then select an entire week regardless of the date chosen. Even though you select Tuesday, Monday until Sunday is the output.